# Flask setting cookies

Tags: python, cookies, flask

I try to set cookies in Flask, but I don't get what I want to. Instead of getting username I get an respone attached to my URL. 
My **routes.py**

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
        if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=form.remember_me.data)

        userCookie = request.form['username']
        resp = make_response(render_template('index.html'))
        resp.set_cookie('user', userCookie)
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
            next_page = url_for('index', resp=resp)
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In', form=form)
```

And I want to display the content of cooki in **index.html**

```
{% for r in resp %}
  {{ r }}
{% endfor %}
```

Instead I get:

```
index?resp<Response+1250+bytes+[200+OK]>
```

What am I doing wrong?

[EDIT - logout method]

That's my method before adding cookies

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
  logout_user()
  return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

So if I added cookies:

```
@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    resp = make_response(redirect('/login'))
    resp.delete_cookie('user')
```

And if I rester server, login, the cookie is created, but after logout I can even go to the endpoint /login
        return resp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies are set in one request and can be used in another request.

To overcome this, use `redirect` in `make_response`.

I have attached an example of login/logout functionalities using cookies:

`app.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, make_response, flash, redirect

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'SUPER SECRET'

@app.route('/', methods = ['GET'])
def home():
    username = request.cookies.get('username')
    if username:
        return render_template('home.html', username=username)
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/login', methods = ['GET','POST'])
def login():
    username = request.cookies.get('username')
    if username:
        return render_template('login.html', username=username)
    if request.method=='POST':
        username = request.form.get('username')
        password = request.form.get('password')
        if username=='admin' and password=='admin':
            flash("Successful login", "success")
            resp = make_response(redirect('/'))
            resp.set_cookie('username', username)
            return resp
        else:
            flash("Wrong username or password", "danger")
    return render_template('login.html')

@app.route('/logout', methods = ['GET'])
def logout():
    resp = make_response(redirect('/'))
    resp.delete_cookie('username')
    return resp
app.run(debug=True)
```

`home.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
          {% if messages %}
            <ul class=flashes>
            {% for message in messages %}
              <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}
        {% if username %}
            Welcome {{ username }}. 
            <a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Click here</a> to logout.
        {% else %}
            You are not logged in.          
            <a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Click here</a> to login.
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

`login.html`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
          {% if messages %}
            <ul class=flashes>
            {% for message in messages %}
              <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            </ul>
          {% endif %}
        {% endwith %}

        {% if username %}
            You are already logged in as{{ username }}.
            <a href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Click here</a> to go to home.
            <a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Click here</a> to logout.
        {% else %}
            <form method="post" action="">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/> 
                <br/>

                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/> 
                <br/>

                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login"/> 
            </form>
        {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

**Screenshots:**

**1. Before login (no cookie):**

[image: before login]

**2. Login (no cookie):**

[image: login]

**3. After login (received cookie):**

[image: after login]

**4. After Logout (no cookie):**

[image: after logout]

Comment: Ok, it works fine to some extend. If i login in to website, the cookie and session is created. The cookie has value of my user. But after logout, the cookie is removed and I can login in again. I can even display my login form

Comment: I assume the problem is now in logout functionality. Can you update the question including the logout snippet?

Comment: What happens if you add `logout_user()` at the first line in my logout method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to return resp directly, `make_response` Convert the return value from a view function to an instance of response_class.

```
userCookie = request.form['username']
resp = make_response(render_template('index.html'))
resp.set_cookie('user', userCookie)
next_page = request.args.get('next')
if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).netloc != '':
    return resp
```

In the html, get the cookie by javascript

```
<label id="label_id1"></label>

<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(document.cookie);
    document.getElementById('label_id1').innerhtml = document.cookie
</script>
```